# R2dbc real time updates from relational DB

Tags: reactive, r2dbc, rdbms

Does R2dbc support instant updates if some proces inserts, updates, deletes data directly from SQL databases?
Or does it only support publishing of such events when data modification actions are done via R2dbc?
When I tried running queries and expose as WebFlux stream the stream was completed after successfully streaming all query rrsults
Is there a cold / hot Flux that will get either whole result set streamed on new subscription or only modified row(s) for existing / new subscriptions ?

Comment: Are you searching for streaming continuous change stream from database query? If yes, ReThinkDB seems as one solution (it is not a sql DB through) or something like debezium can be helpful for achieving that sort of thing with traditional DB. (r2dbc seems unable to deliver thhis out-of-box. Perhaps you can try to use triggers and channels to emulate similar use-case.)

Comment: You need support of this in your DB. Postgres has pg_notify functionality. Example of this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763767/spring-r2dbc-is-there-are-way-to-get-constant-stream-from-postgresql-database-a/74689270#74689270